# How to populate choices in second dropdown on the basis of selected value from first dropdown in Django using ModelChoiceFields for both dropdown

Tags: django, modelchoicefield

I have two dropdown:

1. Category
2. Sub Category

Both needs to be populated dynamically

Here I want to populate choices in sub_category on the basic of selected value from category field.
So i don't need to save the whole form.

```
class AddProductForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    queryset=Category.objects.all(), to_field_name="category")
    sub_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Comment: you can use `django_select2` [link](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html)

Comment: getting both dropdowns blank now.

Comment: posted an example

Answer (score 0):

example with django_select2
`models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name='Category title', max_length=100, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name_category',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Category', related_name='sub')
    name_subcategory = models.CharField(verbose_name='Subcategory title', max_length=100, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('category', 'name_subcategory',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subcategory


class Product(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Category', related_name='prod')
    name_product = models.CharField(verbose_name='Product title', max_length=100, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Price')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name_product', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_product
```

`forms.py`( i used 'style': 'width:350px;' because i don't have any css in this test project)

```
from django import forms
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget
from .models import Category, Subcategory


class AddProductForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            search_fields=['name_category__icontains'],
            attrs={'style': 'width:350px;', },
        )
    )
    sub_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            attrs={'style': 'width:350px;', },
            model=Subcategory,
            search_fields=['name_subcategory__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'category': 'category'},

        ),
        queryset=Subcategory.objects.all(),
    )
```

`views.py`

```
from .forms import AddProductForm


class AddProductView(FormView):
    form_class = AddProductForm
    template_name = "categories/new_product.html"
```

`new_product.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_JQUERY"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
    <form>
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

you also need to put     `path('select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),` into your `urls.py`, `'django_select2'` into yout `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
Other thing to mention, that dependent fields work only inside one form and `form` tag is mandatory